# Smarty Arithmetic Operations

Tags: html, smarty

I have a for loop and want to display on the smarty page with some arithmetic manipulations

```
<tr>
    <td>{$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].main_category}</td>
    <td>{$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].category}</td>
    <td>{$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].name}</td>
    <td>{$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].stock-$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].deliver}</td>
    <td>{$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].price}</td>
    <td>{math equation="( x * z )" x=$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].stock-$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].deliver  z=$_available_stockDataList[mcrList].price}</td>
</tr>
```

for last cell I used smarty math tag.
When $_available_stockDataList[mcrList].price is zero it is getting error.parameter z is empty

How can I fix this?

Comment: is it *numeric* zero or null, empty string or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

wrap this function with an

```
{if $_available_stockDataList[mcrList].price != 0}...{/if}
```

Or If you want add an {else} part also.